# Cornerstone "An error occurred and the operation could not be completed" at startup, what to do?

Tags: cornerstone

Cornerstone "An error occurred and the operation could not be completed" at startup, what to do?

I'm getting a window with "An error occurred and the operation could not be completed". When I proceed it "unexpectedly quits". I already reinstalled the software, but the error keeps coming. What to do?

Here's part of the report:

```
"Process:               Cornerstone [846]
Path:                  /Applications/Cornerstone.app/Contents/MacOS/Cornerstone
Identifier:            com.zennaware.Cornerstone
Version:               2.7.17 (2.7.17)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Cornerstone [846]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-20 10:32:13.913 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        3865FC3A-AB3C-183E-A260-CB2C4EB5D747


Time Awake Since Boot: 3600 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same problem . Just to solve. Open your finder->yourusername->Library->Application Support->Cornerstone,and remove everything in there.
But after that you need to reset Cornerstone setting..

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I wasn't able to find the files at first, but I didn't look under "myusername".

Comment: I don't find any Cornerstone in this directory. I am using the OS 12

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced this too, and the answer above was helpful. However, I couldn't afford to lose all of my data and start again so I decided to dig a little deeper.

The problem appears to be some corruption in the file `~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases/WorkingCopies.db` - you can actually leave `~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases/Repositories.db` as is, and not lose any of the repositories. I've found that both of the files are XML files and `WorkingCopies.db`, for example, can be edited so that most of the information can be saved (the structure is relatively simple but you'd want to get an idea of the relationships between folders and working copies - and back-up, of course.).

This is too late for the OP, but it may help someone else.

Edit: It is in fact possible to recovery the entire file.

- Shut down Cornerstone (Not that you can start it at all! LOL!) and move `~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases/WorkingCopies.db` somewhere else.
- Restart Cornerstone. It should start ok, without any working copies.
- Shutdown Cornerstone.
- Look in the new `~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases/WorkingCopies.db` file.
- From the old file, copy from `<object type="REGISTRYFOLDER" id="z102">` to the last `</object>` (should be the second last line).
- Replace the same in the newly generated file.
- You may need to make sure that the value in `<nextObjectID>102</nextObjectID>` matches the number (and number only) in the id attribute in the first `<object type="REGISTRYFOLDER" id="z102">` node.
- Save the file and restart Cornerstone.

Cornerstone was updated recently and I suspect that there may have been some formatting change or small bug.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same symptoms and also had several dozen working copies I didn't want to reconfigure. Using the ideas from the previous answers, I was able to restore to working order by backing up my WorkingCopies.db file, letting Cornerstone generate a new one, then replacing the new one with my backup:

- Rename `~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases/WorkingCopies.db` to `WorkingCopies.db.bak`
- Open Cornerstone (should be successful, but without existing working copies)
- Quit Cornerstone
- Copy `WorkingCopies.db.bak` to `WorkingCopies.db` (replacing the new one that was just created when opening Cornerstone)
- Open Cornerstone to confirm it has the restored working copies configuration

My conclusion is that the WorkingCopies.db itself isn't corrupted but Cornerstone somehow had a reference to it that did get corrupted. A little reset and all is good.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your repository and/or working copy registration databases have been corrupted. To verify this:

1. Quit Cornerstone
2. In Finder, Select Go->Go to Folder...
3. Enter:

~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases

4. Click Go.
5. Move Working Copies.db  to the Trash.
6. Restart Cornerstone

If that does not fix the problem:

7. Quit Cornerstone
8. In Finder, Select Go->Go to Folder...
9. Enter:

~/Library/Application Support/Cornerstone/Registration Databases

10. Click Go.
11. Move Repositories.db  to the Trash.
12. Restart Cornerstone

If either of these works you'll end up loosing your working copy and/or repository registrations (not the actual files themselves, just Cornerstone's registrations). In either case, you'll have to re-add them to the application.

Answer (score 2):

Quick workaround to open Cornerstone without losing your repositories:

1. Go to Terminal. `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Cornerstone/`. Type `open .` to open the path.
2. Move `Registration Databases` and `Transcripts` to Trash.
3. Force quit (Command-Option-Esc) Cornerstone, if you haven't already.
4. Open Cornerstone. You'll see all repos are gone.
5. Go to Trash and hit undo (Command+Z) or restore `Registration Databases` and `Transcripts` by replacing them on the new folders created at Step 1.
6. You'll get your all repositories back and Cornerstone running.

Comment: I have no Cornerstone in this directory cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/